Error in my yaml when running pipeline exit code 4
I am getting an error below when running my pipeline. It is using only a simple windows OS patching and I cant find where it is failing.
[WARNING]: Collection ansible.windows does not support Ansible version 2.10.17
ERROR! conflicting action statements: hosts, gather_facts

The error appears to be in '/__w/14/s/playbooks/roles/tenant_gain_OSPatching/tasks/main.yml': line 1, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Patching Windows systems
  ^ here
##[error]Script failed with exit code: 4
/usr/local/bin/az account clear

Below is the sample code I have
- name: Patching Windows systems
  hosts: windows
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Install all available updates
      win_updates:
        category_names:
          - SecurityUpdates
          - CriticalUpdates
        reboot: yes
      register: update_result

    - name: Reboot if required
      win_reboot:
      when: update_result.reboot_required


What is the version of Ansible.Windows?


What's the version of your ansible.windows? 2. If you can run your Ansible playbooks successfully on your local machine? If it works locally, the issue may be related to your pipeline. If not, it may be related to your Ansible playbooks. 3. Please share your completed yaml file used to run DevOps pipeline. (Including the agent you used.) 4. Add a variable system.debug and set the value to true. Then trigger the pipeline and check if there is any detailed error message.


The Ansible Exit Code means either the hosts were not reachable or there was a parser error, which is the fact in your case. IT seems to be a syntax error, also also according ERROR! conflicting action statements: hosts, gather_facts but without any further information an your complete YAML files we can't say where. Maybe it's caused by somehting like Import a playbook into another playbook without its' defined hosts.
